# Is there a way to intercept requests to a specific directory and then choose how i want to respond to that request?

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I want to try and build a lazy load plugin for a dummy wordpress site that I manage. I want to do it in this way for experience.

How could I go about intercepting calls to my images folder and then decide if I should return those images or if I should hold off?

Ideally the way that I thought this would work is I would wait for the request. If there are 15 images on the page then I would return the first half and hold off on the second. Once the user scrolls to a certain point then ajax would fire and request the rest.

The purpose of this is so that it doesn't require as much configuration.

What is the standard approach to lazy loading? And then is there a way that I could accomplish what I am trying to do? Is the standard approach better than what I envision?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to load a first batch of 15 images, then loading them 15 by 15 (or whatever amount) using some ajax requests and javascript code as you reach some point while navigating on the page.

This shouldn't have to do with the server, otherwise you are complicating things.

Comment: How would I go about that though? I didn't think there would be a way to control the dom before it starts requests... How would I prevent the rest from being loaded without having to hard code something specific in? My goal it to make this very plug and play.

Comment: @krizper From what I have read, there's quite some override to do, and it has to do with src and srcset attributes for loading images. Best example I found is https://macarthur.me/posts/build-your-own-simple-lazy-loading-functionality-in-wordpress and another article but it's in French. 
You may want to have a look at how both Lozad and BJ Lazy loader are built to get an idea how you should start